# Row count in SQL while doing Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have 3 update statements on a single table and i need to get the Rowcount for each update option in SQL server 2008

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Store `@@ROWCOUNT` after each update in a variable and then use `SELECT` to return them

```
DECLARE @rowcount1 INT
DECLARE @rowcount2 INT
DECLARE @rowcount3 INT

-- UPDATE 1.... then
SET @rowcount1 = @@ROWCOUNT

-- UPDATE 2.... then
SET @rowcount2 = @@ROWCOUNT

-- UPDATE 3.... then
SET @rowcount3 = @@ROWCOUNT

SELECT @rowcount1, @rowcount2, @rowcount3
```

Answer (score 1):

[@@ROWCOUNT](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms187316.aspx&rct=j&q=%40%40ROWCOUNT&ei=eowrTfD-B8GqlAfM1uiKAg&usg=AFQjCNE-jiBtvjNKYOD5wUVxQV38NuFwjw&sig2=kYtDlk62mK7h1-CmG6LQXw&cad=rja) will give you the number of rows affected by an update statement.